# Bootstrap 4 Carousel caption does not show under 768px

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to style my carousel caption but i saw if i minimize the screen,

the caption just disappears i saw a answer on another post that u need to remove
the d-block d-m-block but that doesn't helps

Is that a bootstrap 3 feature or something?

Cause now it's just disappearing

EDIT:

```
                <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="slide2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Parapgrah</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you show us some code, or at least add an example. js fiddle maybe

Comment: I edited the post for u my froend

Comment: That's just the html, it tells us nothing on its own. We also need to see the relevant CSS and jquery because this is what is controlling the display of the caption. As @Stavm suggested, please provide a working code snippet or fiddle so that we can actually see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need delete from 
`<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">`

next classes

**d-none d-md-block**